# How to move window by right mouse button using C++?

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to move window by right mouse button. The window has no caption, titlebar. By left button it works

```
 void CMyHud::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    SendMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE|0x0002);
    CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

But if I place this code on OnRButtonDown it dosen't work. What is the problem?

**Well, the solution is found, thanks to Mark Ransom:**

```
 CRect pos;

   void CMyHud::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
    {
        pos.left = point.x;
        pos.top = point.y;
        ::SetCapture(m_hWnd);

        CDialogEx::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    }


    void CMyHud::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
    {
        CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(m_hWnd);
        CRect r;
        if(GetCapture() == pWnd)
        {
            POINT pt;
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            GetWindowRect(r);
            pt.x -= pos.left;
            pt.y -= pos.top;
            MoveWindow(pt.x, pt.y, r.Width(), r.Height(),TRUE);
        }

        CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
    }


    void CMyHud::OnRButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();

        CDialogEx::OnRButtonUp(nFlags, point);
    }
```

Comment: Does `OnRButtonDown` get called?

Comment: You are right OnRbuttonDown is get called but no movement happen for the dialog, I'm trying to find out why it works only with OnLButtonDown.

Comment: Yes, OnRButtonDown called!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `OnRButtonDown` function, do a [`SetCapture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2b3a4c.aspx) to ensure all mouse messages are routed to your window while the mouse button is down. Also store the mouse position in a member variable. Now, in your `OnMouseMove` function, check to see if [`GetCapture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxa5eaaa.aspx) returns an object with the same HWND as yours - if it does, calculate the difference between the current mouse position and the saved one, then call [`MoveWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bc5w1zz.aspx) to move the window.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to left-mouse click:

`SC_MOVE|0x0002` comes out as `0xF012` or `SC_DRAGMOVE`. This is apparently an undocumented constant. There is probably a good reason Microsoft doesn't want anybody to use this, that's why they have hidden it.

Also `WM_SYSCOMMAND` is a notification message. You should respond to it, not send it. To drag the window with left-mouse click:

```
message map ...
ON_WM_NCHITTEST()

LRESULT CMyDialog::OnNcHitTest(CPoint p)
{
    //responding to a notification message
    return HTCAPTION; 
}
```

To drag the window with right-mouse you have to override OnRButtonDown, OnMouseMove, OnRButtonUp and make your own routine. But Window's behaviour gets very confusing. Is that really worth it?

Comment: With left mouse button it works perfectly. I need right button. The solution is found by your and marks advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use mouse message to realize.
WM_RBUTTONDOWN,   WM_MOUSEMOVE