# How to dock a borderless form?

Tags: delphi

I have a "borderless" Form with property `WindowState = wsMaximized`.
I can drag the form with this code in the `OnMouseDown` event of a Panel on the Form:

```pascal
procedure TForm10.Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if button = mbLeft then begin
    ReleaseCapture();
    Self.Perform( WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_DRAGMOVE, 0 );
  end;
end;
```

But, after dragging, the Form loses its ability to dock all over the window.

How can I force the Form to dock again, as if it was a bordered Form?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of what you are doing. Why would you want to drag a maximized window?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I want to drag the form to the second monitor and it must be maximized there as was on first monitor. The form must be borderless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, even though you react on the `MouseDown` event of the panel, you must react to the `MouseUp` event of the *form*.

First define the `OnMouseUp` event for the borderless form. Add code to change the `WindowState` of the form to `wsMaximized`. It should look something like this:

```
procedure TForm9.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  WindowState := wsMaximized;
end;
```

Then modify your `OnMouseDown` event to include a call to `OnMouseUp()` event:

```
procedure TForm9.Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const
  SC_DRAGMOVE = $F012;
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then begin
    ReleaseCapture;
    Self.Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_DRAGMOVE, 0);
    if Assigned(OnMouseUp) then
      FormMouseUp(Sender, Button, Shift, X, Y);
  end;
end;
```

I have no means to test this in a secondary monitor, but possibly it detects that it is maximized on the second monitor and works as you wish.

Comment: If this is the solution then JimPapas **again** forgot an [already existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76649566/4299358).